# Flattening nested objects without a TS error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an edit form for my company and someone on my team decided to change the formatting of our API payload return without consulting the rest of the team and now we are playing catchup.

Since the API called we have to post the value back to the DB are not set up for nested objects, I need to flatten it so I can manipulate the values and submit it.

Here is the new nested structure

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "data" : {
            "name": "Tank",
            "dimensions": "2.0 x 2.5 x 4.0"
       }
    }
```

and I need to convert it back to something like this:

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "name": "Tank",
       "dimensions": "2.0 x 22.5 x 4.0"
    }
```

I found multiple solutions online, but all of them are giving me the same TypeScript error

*"for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement"*

I am also seeing the a lot of them are embedding the name of for first element in from of its nested element, like this:

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "data.name": "Tank",
       "data.dimensions": "2.0 x 22.5 x 4.0"
    }
```

Can someone show me how to rewrite this flatten function where it eliminates the TS error and doesn't append the first level element's name to its nested elements, leaving me with simple single level object?

Here is my flatten function:

```
const obj = values;

const flattenObj = (ob) => {
  // The object which contains the final result
  const result = {};
  // loop through the object "ob"
  for (const i in ob) {
      // We check the type of the i using typeof() function and recursively call the function again
      if ((typeof ob[i]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(ob[i])) {
          const temp = flattenObj(ob[i]);
          for (const j in temp) {
              // Store temp in result
              result[i + '.' + j] = temp[j];
          }
      }
      // Else store ob[i] in result directly
      else {
          result[i] = ob[i];
      }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(flattenObj(ob));
```

Comment: Part of the reason it gives you that error is because `for...in` *walks the prototype chain*, which doesn't matter in your example input but very much matters for flattening *in general*. The compiler is trying to warn you there's (at least one) edge case your code doesn't cover.

Comment: so how do I fix it? guessing i need some sort of if statement, but it already has one.

Comment: I wrote up an answer

Comment: Oh!  I'm sorry. I didn't see it a minute ago.

Comment: No worries let me know if it works for you

Comment: Man, I truly hate typescript.  It is still throwing the same error on the line "for (const j in temp)", so I guess that was the line giving me hits all along

Comment: "I am slos seeing the a lot og them are " say what?

Comment: You're using the term "JSON" to mean object, which is not correct. JSON is a text format.

Comment: BTW, _Typescript_ is not doing this.  Your linter is catching the (very real) error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
let jsonObj = {
  status: 1,
  data: {
    name: "someStatus",
    dimensions: "2.0 x 2.5 x 4.0",
    some: {
      city: "somecity",
      dimensions: "somedimensions",
      next: {
        type: "nextType",
        value: "nextValue",
      },
    },
  },
};
 

function builder(obj : Record<string,any>, temp:Record<string,string | number | boolean>) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[keys] == "object") {
      builder(obj[keys], temp);
    } else {
      temp[keys] = obj[keys];
    }
  }

  return temp;
}

let result = builder(jsonObj,{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Answers are almost always better with an explanation of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could change

```
for (const i in ob) { .. }
```

to

```
for (const [i, obi] of Object.entries(ob)) { // use obi instead of ob[i] }
```

that way you're not touching the prototype stuff at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  "status": 1, 
  "data" : {
    "name": "Tank",
    "dimensions": "2.0 x 2.5 x 4.0"
  }
};

const flattenObj = (ob: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  const result: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  for (const i in ob) {
      if (ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        const val = ob[i];
        if (val && typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
          const temp = flattenObj(val as Record<string, unknown>);
          for (const j in temp) {
              result[i + '.' + j] = temp[j];
          }
        }
        else {
          result[i] = ob[i];
        }
      }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(flattenObj(obj));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAiaAhlAK4S4BcMAjADQzZ4AmRBuMlWOOuYBAtgFMKeACoEwAa1w0G3RgEtBkeeDKVcAJgB0ABhgAPGNoCsBmABZduBgF9MNgNyZMoSLABmAGyJQBYAPJIqDAAFAiUAEoCoABOjAA80DHyYADmdMSSYCAA7mAAfACUqPkYDK7QMDECEMSeUJHRIHGJUMlpGVm5BcHojgzuzaEVsPIwKXDwxZxcOPLuoQhaABYEEP55AAoxIAAOAjFQAJ4h8oXTsrMwIzAAbgSewQgA2vIAuk5XXPOh948AZP8YMd9iAFn9UCg0AByBCIaJQaEwQEwACEAEEYjECEctPIIJjsSc-ucyl9ZjdfHxdsEvD4-IFECEIWsYFFYgkkil0jBMhJsnkip9yThBjFhqpYMgJlTdhcRV9qrV6q8YABqGDQrRIjWIN7BWXPPXCkV2U2XWYCTwQARkhVKupQV76tAvd4mq5mz22BjVEgxMBVGqOpz9FyqECeARaTwgVIhOlQXwBJBhJDnBxAA)

Some changes from your version:

1. Has `.hasOwnProperty` conditional check to satisfy the lint rule
2. Checks that `ob[i]` is truthy, note that `typeof null === 'object'`!
3. Types the argument and return value as `Record<string, unknown>`. For truly dynamic objects (like the response from an API call) you won't know the type. If you narrow the type of the data to a specific schema you could *probably* use template literal types and generics to make a type-safe more specific return value. I'm still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using a recursive function.

In case the `obj[key]` is a simple value like `obj['status']`, it is added directly to the result object.

Otherwise, if the `obj[key]` is an object like the value of `obj['data']`, the `flattenJSON` function is called using `obj['data']` as a parameter. Once done, the result is concatenated with the previous result.

This function handles multiple nesting as well.

Note: The parentKey is not wanted. Consequently, some keys might be overridden.

```
type JsonObject = Record<string, unknown>;

function flattenJSON(jsonObj: JsonObject): Record<string, unknown> {
  let result: Record<string, unknown> = {};

  for (const key in jsonObj) {
    if (typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object' &&!Array.isArray(jsonObj[key])) {
      const flattened = flattenJSON(jsonObj[key] as JsonObject);
      result = { ...result, ...flattened };
    } else {
      result[key] = jsonObj[key];
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `any` here, as it basically disables all typechecking of those values. The `unknown` type would be a better option.

Comment: indeed, thank you. I updated the function accordingly.

Comment: Answers are almost always better with an explanation of the code.